# I want to replace one collection with another in MongoDB using NodeJS/Mongoose, Should I use renameCollection and how?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, mongoose

I have two collections with identical schema but different content. I would like to drop the first one and rename the second with the name of the first. I noticed that MongoDB has a function called renameCollection that would do the job perfectly, however I am struggling to find a way to implement it using Mongoose. Any solutions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with the `mongo` shell if you only have 1 instance of your DB to worry about. If you want to do it as a migration script you can run across a bunch of instances of the DB you can implement it as a shell script a la:

```
#!/bin/sh
mongo localhost/mydb --eval 'db.oldCollection.renameCollection("newCollection", true);'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would still be more keen on mongoose implementation for consistency. I need to do this replacement at least few times per hour, so sadly it is not one off. But I will keep this option if there is no solution through mongoose.